# ionic2 tabs getSelected Method gives previous selection

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic2, ionic3

following is the code i am working on

```
onTabsChange(abc) {
   let selected_tab = this.tabs.getSelected();
   let tab_index = selected_tab.index;
   console.log(tab_index);  // should print current tab index but it prints previously selected tab index
}
```

And Following is the Html code

```
 <ion-tabs #myTabs class="menu" (ionChange)="onTabsChange()" selectedIndex="0">
   <ion-tab [root]="blank" tabTitle="Blank"></ion-tab>
   <ion-tab [root]="blank" tabTitle="Blank"></ion-tab>
   <ion-tab [root]="blank" tabTitle="Blank"></ion-tab>
   <ion-tab [root]="blank" tabTitle="Blank"></ion-tab>
   <ion-tab [root]="blank" tabTitle="Blank"></ion-tab>
   <ion-tab [root]="blank" tabTitle="Blank"></ion-tab>
   <ion-tab [root]="blank" tabTitle="Blank"></ion-tab>
 </ion-tabs>
```

Now if i click on any tab, the this.tabs.getSelected() gives me the previously selected tab..

if i want the current selected tab how can i achieve this..

Answer (score 6):

> Now if i click on any tab, the this.tabs.getSelected() gives me the
>   previously selected tab..

The `getSelected()` method returns the selected tab and *not the previously selected tab*. The thing is that the index is a **zero based index** so the first tab has 0 as index, the second one has 1, and so on...

```
<ion-tabs #myTabs (ionChange)="onTabsChange()" selectedIndex="0">
  <ion-tab [root]="tab1Root" tabTitle="TabTitle1"></ion-tab>
  <ion-tab [root]="tab2Root" tabTitle="tabTitle2"></ion-tab>
</ion-tabs>
```

And then in your code:

```
@Component({
  templateUrl: 'tabs.html'
})
export class TabsPage {
  @ViewChild('myTabs') tabRef: Tabs;

  tab1Root: any = Page1;
  tab2Root: any = Page2;

  public onTabsChange() {
    let selectedTab = this.tabRef.getSelected();
    console.log(selectedTab.index + ' - ' + selectedTab.tabTitle);
  }
}
```

Comment: its not working for me .. can it be due to version i have ionic 2.0.0 version installed

Comment: I'll create a project with the new RC and test this there :)

Comment: Also when app starts this line returns undefined this.tabs.getSelected(); i guess there is some issue with version it self.. i will try updating to higher version